# How to group / Compress tags in Sublime Text 3

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I recently switch to Sublime Text 3 from Dreamweaver. I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> for grouping HTML in there so I am looking for its alternative in Sublime Text 3. This feature is available in Sublime Text 3? because I could not find the the key or in menu.

```
<div>
<div>
<p>
<span></span>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

**into**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by group tags?

Comment: Ctrl + Shift J Compress selected object tag from http://www.dreamweavershortcuts.co.uk/pages/CTRLkey.htm

Answer (score 2):

Sublime Text can only indent via whitespace. So if you have this:

```
<div>
<div>
<p>
<span></span>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Then Sublime can't fold it. You need to indent like so:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <p>
            <span></span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And now, you'll see fold icons in the gutter - they may be a bit faint. To fold via the keyboard, you can do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>0-9</kbd>, or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> to fold and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to unfold.

If it's tag attributes you want to fold, then you can do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

- If you're on OSX, then it's <kbd>CMD</kbd> instead of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>.

Comment: For indentation you can select the the text and choose Edit > Line > Indent